# How to know the floating point precision? Specifically, for GPS coordinates is it safe to use double?

Tags: floating-point, gps, coordinates, precision

Generally, what is the error I get when using a floating point number?
Specifically, is it safe to store GPS coordinates as double floating point numbers?

I think yes. Assuming "safe" to be "6 decimal digits, the same as google maps". I used the following code for verification. It uses Math.ulp of Java.

```
class Ulp {

        public static void main(String[]  args) {

              double ulp = Math.ulp(new Double("-181")), ulp2;

              for (double d=new Double("-181"); d<=181; d++) {
                ulp2=Math.ulp(d);
                if (ulp2 != ulp) {
                  System.out.println(""+ulp+" "+ulp2+" "+d);
                  ulp = ulp2;
                }

              }

        }
}
```

From this I get the worst error is 2.8421709430404007E-14, which is safe.

Can you reassure me this reasoning is correct?

Comment: I guess it depends on what you use them for. For calculations (e.g. of distances or some such), you can use doubles. For storage, just to be sure, I would rather use strings, or fixed point types (i.e. scaled integers or longs).

Comment: Just use doubles.  The precision of a double > precision of GPS, there's no accuracy loss.  There's no point in using fixed point if there's not going to be accuracy loss, and when almost every API will feed you doubles rather than strings to begin with.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, doubles have 15 digits of relative precision, which corresponds to roughly nanometre resolution of GPS coordinates.